# Облик легко узнаваем — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

-

Answer (score 2):

Значение фразы "легко узнаваем" не является терминологическим, поэтому пишем раздельно. (Хотя, конечно,  чтобы говорить наверняка, не мешало бы контекста побольше.)
**Легкоузнаваемый** (в полной форме) - в словаре "Слитно или раздельно?" Б.З. Букчиной написано слитно. Есть помета: в **не**терминологическом значении пишется **раздельно**.  Слов с начальным ЛЕГКО очень много: ***легкоусвояемый, легкоувлажняемый, легкоуязвимый...*** И все с той же пометой:в **не**терминологическом значении пишется **раздельно**. 
Там же: ***легко раненный и легкораненый***.
В Вашем предложении причастие УЗНАВАЕМ ещё и в краткой форме употреблено. Сказуемое получается. УЗНАВАЕМ как? в какой мере, степени? ЛЕГКО - обстоятельство.

Comment: Думаю, контекст ничего не изменит. Я даже в принципе не могу предстваить что-то, что изменило бы написание.  
Вот вопрос терминологичности - и применение его по отношению к кратким формам мне не совсем понятен. Гипотетически "легкоузнаваемый" может быть термином. Но если это облик, то вряд ли.

Answer (score 0):

Такие конструкции, состоящие из прилагательного или причастия в сочетании с наречием обычно пишутся раздельно. Исключение составляют случаи, когда это сочетание превратилось в термин: вечнозеленые растения, тяжелораненый боец, малосоленая вода и т.п. Так что в приведенной Вами фразе - раздельное написание